# how get user change devices name from google home app?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm creating IOT device and I started developing google home assistant,
in order to change names from the device I use the req_sync which update the names, but if the user change the names from the google home app I don't get any event and I can't figure out how to get the device name in order to update it from my side.

is there any known way to get the changed devices names?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the user set nicknames for a device, and no push notification to to your service.

Comment: but when I set the name and req_sync it's rewrite the device name in the user google home app